# Client Certificate on a Google Chromecast

Tags: chromecast, x509

I would like to connect a Chromecast to a wifi network where access is secured by certificates (plus username/pwd).

Does anyone know whether you can install a certificate on a Google Chromecast and can it pass the cert for secured access?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot install any certificates on a chromecast device.

Comment: Do you know of any links to documentation to that effect?